# Should foreign words like "mapo" be italicized?

Tags: style

Some foreign words have made it to most English dictionaries. Like [tempura](https://www.google.com/search?q=tempura%20define&sxsrf=APq-WBvD7YdJbt07RxsgrReyR54mi3pDIA%3A1649172456685&ei=6F9MYtHGKdr1-QbczKP4Ag&ved=0ahUKEwjR2tCTnv32AhXaet4KHVzmCC8Q4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=tempura%20define&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCAgAEAcQChAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIFCAAQgAQyCggAEAgQBxAKEB4yBggAEAUQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjIGCAAQCBAeOgcIABBHELADOgcILhCwAxBDOggIABAIEAcQHkoECEEYAEoECEYYAFCSI1idJ2CGKGgCcAF4AIABPogB4AKSAQE3mAEAoAEByAEJwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz).

If a foreign word, like *mapo* from [mapo tofu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapo_tofu), doesn't show up in English dictionaries (or in very few), is it better to write it in italics (like I just did)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're following APA style, you would italicize the first occurrence of a foreign word that doesn't show up in the dictionary. According to the [APA blog](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/italics-quotations/italics):

> [U]se italics for the following cases:
> First use of words, phrases, or abbreviations from another language when readers may not be familiar with them; however, if the term appears in a dictionary for the language in which you are writing, do not italicize it